# Custom sorting a list of objects efficiently

Tags: python, optimization, performance, sorting, python-2.x

I'm trying to make sorting of objects in my program as fast as possible. I know that sorting with a cmp function is deprecated in python 3.x and that using keys is faster, but I'm not sure how to get the same functionality without using a cmp function.

Here's the definition of the class:

```
class Topic:
    def __init__(self, x, y, val):
        self.id = val
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I have a dictionary full of `Topic` to float key, value pairs and a list of Topics to be sorted. Each topic in the list of `Topic`s to be sorted has an entry in this dictionary. I need to sort the list of topics by the value in the dictionary. If two topics have a difference in value <= .001, the topic with higher ID should come first.

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
topicToDistance = {}
# ...
# topicToDistance populated
# ...
topics = topicToDistance.keys()
def firstGreaterCmp(a, b):
  if abs(topicToDistance[a]-topicToDistance[b]) <= .001:
    if a.id < b.id:
      return 1
  if topicToDistance[a] > topicToDistance[b]:
      return 1
  return -1
# sorting by key may be faster than using a cmp function
topics.sort(cmp = firstGreaterCmp)
```

Any help making this a bit more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what problem you are trying to solve by sorting this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that comparison doesn't have to return `1` or `-1`. For example returning `123` would have the same effect as returning `1`. With this in mind, the `firstGreaterCmp` function could be somewhat simpler:

```
def firstGreaterCmp(a, b):
    difference = topicToDistance[a] - topicToDistance[b]
    if abs(difference) <= .001:
        if a.id < b.id:
            return 1
    return int(difference)
```

On the other hand, the comparison function must return an `int`, and since your value is a `float`, I had to cast it. I don't really know if that has a non-negligible cost or not.

**UPDATE**

Also, as [@janne-karila](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10916/janne-karila) pointed out in a comment,
`int(difference)` is 0 for a range of values (due to integer truncation),
while your original code never returns 0.
It depends on your use case whether this is acceptable or not.

---

In the `Topic` class, I find it somewhat strange that the `id` parameter comes last in the parameter list.
Normally I would expect an id field to be the first.

---

Your code doesn't follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It would be better this way:

```
def firstGreaterCmp(a, b):
    if abs(topicToDistance[a] - topicToDistance[b]) <= .001:
        if a.id < b.id:
            return 1
    if topicToDistance[a] > topicToDistance[b]:
        return 1
    return -1

# sorting by key may be faster than using a cmp function
topics.sort(cmp=firstGreaterCmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the styling guidelines. Do you think there's a way to keep from having to access the dictionary for every comparison? Right now topicToDistance is accessed 2 times for every comparison. Considering the worst case access time for dictionaries is O(n), this could be very costly. Do you see a key I could potentially use in this scenario?

Comment: In the first proposal `int(difference)` is 0 for a range of values, while OP's code never returns 0.

Comment: Thanks @JanneKarila, well spotted, I added a note on that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting algorithms only give consistent results when the comparison function is *transitive*, meaning that whenever A > B and B > C, then also A > C. Your comparison function does not have that property, because you apply a different rule according to the distance between the objects.

This is also why it is not possible to get the same results using a key function (at least not a useful one. Technically you can always convert a comparison function by [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), but that will not make the sorting faster or consistent.)

---

If want to do this anyway, hoping that the data you will be given won't contain any groups of items whose order is ambiguos, you could try an approach where you sort two times: first by key (distance, -id), then by your comparison function. Python's Timsort algorithm  is optimized to deal efficiently with partially sorted data. Therefore the first sorting step should minimize the number of comparisons in the second step.

Comment: I agree the function is not transitive. The rule is not something I can change though. This program is for a coding challenge. http://www.quora.com/challenges#nearby if you are interested.